# Tags friends photo

Tags: php, facebook, tags, photo

I use this codes , but I get an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id thrown in /home/a283357/public_html/app/base_facebook.php on line 1106

MY codes are for tags

```
$data = array(array('tag_uid' => $friends, 'x' => rand() % 100, 'y' => rand() % 100 ));
$data = json_encode($data);
//, 'tags' => $data,


$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'message ', 'tags' => $data, 'image' => '@' . realpath($file) );
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

And I want to tags 5 or 10 friends

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify the tags for photo while creating it. Also you using wrong names for parameters used in create photo method.

You should create the photo first and then tag it.

Create photo:

```
$photo_details = array(
  'message'=> 'message ',
  'source' => '@' . realpath($file)
);
$uploaded_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Now tag it:

```
$tags = array(
  array('tag_uid' => $friend_id, 'x' => rand() % 100, 'y' => rand() % 100 )
);
$photo_id = $uploaded_photo['id'];
$facebook->api('/'.$photo_id.'/tags', 'post', array('tags'=>$tags));
```

**BEWARE,** [documentation states `to` parameter](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags) as one to specify the tagged user, but it's not (it's `tag_uid` as in your initial sample).

Comment: I get this error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Array thrown in /home/a283357/public_html/app/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Comment: @AiBossi, there was a mistake in code sample that should be fixed now.

Comment: again error Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid keys "to" were found in param "tags". thrown in /home/a283357/public_html/app/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Comment: Again show Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#121) Invalid photo id thrown in /home/a283357/public_html/app/base_facebook.php on line 1106

Comment: @AiBossi, sample code doesn't contain any error handling ensure the second request for tagging photo contain correct `id` of photo. You may want to `print_r($uploaded_photo)` before tagging the photo. For me it's perfectly working that way.

Comment: @AiBossi, what do you mean by "second time"? Every request for tagging photo should be done to `https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/tags` if you want to tag photo you didn't uploaded you need to know the `id` of photo.

Comment: The problem is about photo id .When I use https://graph.facebook.com/414030735274837/ show false .Something wrong with photo id

Comment: You should be able to access the photo of user/friends with `access_token` of user who granted `user_photos`/`friends_photos` permission.